# Why does the program crash upon printing the two lastnames?

Tags: c, linked-list

It seems that my program crashes upon printing both lastnames, I can't get the reason why this linked list would crash upon printing the two lastnames. Would appreciate any help :((. I was implementing a linked list with multiple elements, however I just printed the last name to see if the list would iterate properly, turns out that it crashes after printing the 2nd lastname "programmer".

```
struct user
{

     char email[30];
     char lastname[30];
     char firstname[30];
     char phonenumber[20]; 
     char status [50];
     char password [50];

};


struct nodeTag {
    struct user  data;
    struct nodeTag *pNext; 
    struct nodeTag *pPrev;
};

typedef struct nodeTag nodeStructType;


int main(){

    nodeStructType *pFirst;
    nodeStructType *pSecond;
    nodeStructType *pRun;

    pFirst = malloc(sizeof(nodeStructType));
    strcpy(pFirst->data.email,"art@yahoo.com");
    strcpy(pFirst->data.password,"artist");
    strcpy(pFirst->data.lastname,"iamaartist");
    strcpy(pFirst->data.firstname,"artist");
    strcpy(pFirst->data.status,"Hello i am a artist");
    strcpy(pFirst->data.phonenumber,"092712345678");
    pSecond= malloc(sizeof(nodeStructType));

    pFirst->pNext=pSecond;
    strcpy(pSecond->data.email,"programming@yahoo.com");
    strcpy(pSecond->data.password,"programmer");
    strcpy(pSecond->data.lastname,"programmer");
    strcpy(pSecond->data.firstname,"programmer");
    strcpy(pSecond->data.status,"Hello i am a programmer");
    strcpy(pSecond->data.phonenumber,"092712345678");


    pRun=pFirst;
    while(pRun->pNext!=NULL){
    printf("%s\n", pRun->data.lastname);
    pRun=pRun->pNext;
   }

}
```

Comment: You need to set `pSecond->pNext = NULL` after you allocate `pSecond`. Otherwise, `while` might attempt to use it if it's not zero.

Comment: Also, what is `nodeStructType`?  That's not in the code you posted.

Comment: that was a typedef sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** As lurker commented above: you need to make sure that your `pNext` pointer is explicitly pointing to `NULL` at the end of your linked list.

When you `malloc()` memory from the system in C, it attempts to find a block big enough to hold whatever it is you're using it for, but performs no cleanup on that memory for you -- you're getting whatever trash the last program didn't clean up. What you're seeing is the while-loop condition not triggering because whatever resides at `pSecond->pNext` isn't a pointer to NULL (0x0).

To top it all off, if you reboot your system and run the program a couple of times, you might get (un)lucky and run into a scenario *where `pSecond->pNext` actually did happen to point to NULL,* leading to quite the confusing situation indeed.

**Bonus:** If you want the function call to handle initializing (to zero) the memory for you, look into `void *calloc(size_t num_elements, size_t element_size);`.